# Jackson Included.NON_DEFAULT not working in 2.7.0

Tags: jackson

I'm trying to upgrade from Jackson 2.3 to Jackson 2.7 , and it appears the  @JsonIgnore(Include.NON_DEFAULT) behavior has changed. 
With the following code

```
package jackson;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
        MyClass foo = new MyClass();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(foo));
    }

    public static enum MyEnum { A, B, C };

    public static class MyClass {
        public String name = "John";

        @JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT) 
        public MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.A;
    }
}
```

I get this output using 2.7:

```
{"name":"John","myEnum":"A"}
```

and the following using 2.3:

```
{"name":"John"}
```

How do I replicate the behavior in 2.3 using version 2.7 ?

Comment: I believe this is a regression bug and have opened a bug report on the Jackson issue tracker for this.  2.6.7 does not have this issue, so you could consider using that if there isn't another 2.7 feature you need.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the bug ticket](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1346#issuecomment-242262691) I put in for this, it is working as intended and that functionality can be achieved by structuring your class as:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public static class MyClass {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
    public String name = "John";

    public MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.A;
}
```

See the ticket for a more thorough explanation from the author.